# Upgrading a framework/library in your project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, diff, libraries

I'm using bootstrap in my Rails project. Now there is an upgrade (v3.3.4) and I wanna upgrade my project to that version. What is the best/most optimal way to do this? I know I can look at the files that have changed and then just replace those files to their respective directories. However, is there a more optimal way to do this without ruining your project?

I guess we could also extend this question to the general case. If you're using a framework or library in your project and there is an upgrade, what is the most efficient way to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal approach to upgrading a framework say, in your case **Twitter Bootstrap**, I would recommened just replacing the current file paths to your css and js on your `<head>....</head>` (or bottom of the page) to a **CDN** (Content Delivery Network) without having to necessarily remove or edit your older files (You can however remove them later at your own sweet time).

Here's a cdn to the latest Bootstrap css:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And here's a cdn to the latest Bootstrap js:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

N.B. **Twitter Bootstrap v3.3.4** is the latest version as of when this answer was posted.